# How do I send a message to all guilds in discord.js with v12+ (12.0.0 and up)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
if (command === "sendguildmessages") {
    if (message.author.id === "231956829159161856") {
        var guildList = client.guilds.array();
        try {
            guildList.forEach(guild => guild.defaultChannel.send("messageToSend"));
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Could not send message to a (few) guild(s)!");
        }
    } else {
        message.reply(`You cant do that!`)
    }
} else
```

I tried using v11.2 but that was a K.O.
It says that it is outdated and needs to be updated. What can I replace with this code?

Comment: So you want to only send the message `"messageToSend"` to 1 channel in each `Guild`, or all `TextChannels` in each `Guild`?

Comment: 1 channel in each guild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defaultChannel()` is already deprecated and has no alternative for it.
And you need to specify the channel on where to send the message, but since some servers have unique channel names, it won't work...unless they all have the same channel name and left it unchanged (some peeps change the name of general).

Well.. I made a code for it (works if the channels have the name "general")

```
if (command === "sendguildmessages") {
  if (message.author.id === "231956829159161856") {
    try {
      let toSay = "messageToSend"
      this.client.guilds.map((guild) => {
        let found = 0
        guild.channels.map((c) => {
          if (found === 0) {
            if (c.type === "text") {
              if (c.permissionsFor(this.client.user).has("VIEW_CHANNEL") === true) {
                if (c.permissionsFor(this.client.user).has("SEND_MESSAGES") === true) {
                  c.send(toSay);
                  found = 1;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        });
      });
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log("Could not send message to a (few) guild(s)!");
    }
  } else {
    message.reply("You cant do that!")
  }
}
```

Taken from: https://github.com/itsYuuki/SmoreBot/blob/master/commands/control/gann.js

Comment: I have tried that but I have this error: `EnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: client.guilds.map is not a function`

Comment: discord.JS now uses cache so you need to use client.guilds.cache and guild.channels.cache