# how to send a message to every channel in every guild?

Tags: discord, discord.js

similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49216044/how-do-i-send-a-message-to-all-guilds-in-discord-js-with-v12-12-0-0-and-up) however I want to be able to send it to every channel it has access to! 
inside the on message event after I verify myself by ID and the issued command I was using this code:

```
      const listedChannels = [];
      msg.guild.channels.forEach(channel => {
      //get all channels
      client.channels.get(channel.id).send("you like bred? (message) ");
      //send a message to every channel in this guild
      });
```

however I get the error that .send is not a function...

I have been told to use `.send` after getting the ID of the channels

Answer (score 0):

If you are looping through all of the channels, you simpily need to send your content to the channel, which you've already gotten from `msg.guild.channels.forEach(channel => {//code})`.

Replace what you have inside the `.forEach` block with;

`channel.send("You like bred? (message)");`

Although this will send `You like bred? (message)`

If you're trying to get a response back, perhaps look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57452056/discord-js-how-to-send-a-message-and-collect-reactions-from-it) that explains collecting responses via reactions to a discord message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `client.channels` for this. Check if channel type is guild **text channel** and then try send a message.

```js
client.channels.forEach(channel => {
    if(channel.type === 'text') channel.send('MSG').catch(console.error)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

*The following explanation pertains only to v11 (stable).*

[`Client.channels`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=channels) is a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) of [Channel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel)s your bot is watching. You can only send messages to text channels, and this Collection will include DM channels as well. For this reason, we can use [`Collection.filter()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter) to retrieve a new Collection of only text channels within a guild. Finally, you can iterate over the channels and call [`TextChannel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) on each. Because you're dealing with [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)s, I'd recommend a [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)/[`Collection.map()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=map) combination *(see hyperlinked documentation)*.

For example...

```js
// assuming "client" is your Discord Bot

const channels = client.channels.filter(c => c.guild && c.type === 'text');
Promise.all(channels.map(c => c.send('Hello, world!')))
  .then(msgs => console.log(`${msgs.length} successfully sent.`))
  .catch(console.error);
```